# How to represent n-cube graph in form of a set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Can we represent an n-cube graph in the form of a set of edges? If so,
then how can we represent a Q4 graph?

Comment: An $n$-cube graph is the graph of two $(n-1)$-cubes linked together $1:1$ on vertices. E.g., the $3$-cube is two $2$-cubes (back and front square faces) linked up bijectively. The $2$-cube is two line segments ($1$-cubes; the top and bottom edges) linked along the verticals.

Comment: e.g for a simple graph we make sets like E={(v1,v2),(v2,v3)} etc. Can we do the same in case of n-cube? Do we have to represent the vertices in form of binary digits in that case?? What will we do in case of Q3 and Q4??(as they are complicated)

Comment: I will write up a proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See here for a pretty good Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph)

Let $\mathcal{V}_n = \{V_{\pm,\pm,\ldots,\pm} = (\pm 1, \pm 1, \ldots, \pm 1)\}$ with $n$ many subscripts denotes the vertex set of $Q_n$, and let $\mathcal{E}_n = \{(V_\alpha, V_\beta)\}$ be its set of (undirected!) edges. Don't worry about the details of $\mathcal{E}_n$ just yet.

We can very easily construct the vertex and edge sets of $Q_{n+1}$. Firstly
$$
\mathcal{V}_{n+1} = \{V_{\alpha, \pm} | V_\alpha \in \mathcal{V}_n\}
$$
which means we take two copies of the vertices of $Q_n$ and add another $\pm$ subscript to keep track of which copy we're in.

Now,
$$
\mathcal{E}_{n+1} = \{(V_{\alpha, +}, V_{\beta, +})| (V_{\alpha}, V_\beta) \in \mathcal{E}_n\} \cup \{(V_{\alpha, -}, V_{\beta, -})| (V_{\alpha}, V_\beta) \in \mathcal{E}_n\} \cup \{(V_{\alpha, +}, V_{\alpha, -})| V_\alpha \in \mathcal{V}_n\}
$$

The first two parts in this union are just the old edges of $Q_n$ `carried over' to their respective $+$ and $-$ copies in $Q_{n+1}$. The third set in the union is just us drawing a new edge for each vertex in $Q_n$; we draw an edge connecting each vertex in the $+$ copy to itself in the $-$ copy.

So you can see we have a process of building $Q_{n+1}$ out of $Q_n$. We have the base case of $Q_1$:
$$
\mathcal{V}_1 = \{V_+, V_{-}\}
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{E}_1 = \{(V_+, V_{-})\}
$$

Starting from this base case (or the case $Q_0$ consisting of one unlabeled vertex and no edges) we can use the above process to produce any $Q_n$ we like.

To answer your commented question, no, it is of course not necessary to use binary strings to index edges/vertices (or as I have done here, $\pm 1$). It is often done for simplicity, as nothing is gained by the extra complication of keeping track of more involved descriptions.

---

Adding to what I said before, given that $\mathcal{V}_1 = \{V_+, V_-\}$ and $\mathcal{E}_1 = \{(V_+, V_-)\}$ we can use the process described above to make
$$
\mathcal{V}_2 = \{V_{++}, V_{-+}, V_{+-}, V_{--}\}
$$
(two copies of $Q_1$, with another $\pm$ label to keep track of which one we're in).

Then also:
$$
\mathcal{E}_2 = \{(V_{++}, V_{-+}), (V_{+-}, V_{--}), (V_{++}, V_{+-}), (V_{-+}, V_{--})\}
$$
the first two of which are just the old edges from the '$+$' and '$-$' copies of $Q_1$, carried over to our construction of $Q_2$. The last two are the new edges we drew between the two copies each vertex, $V_+$ and $V_-$.

Comment: I don't understand the +_ thing what does it imply?

Comment: It's just a label, plus or minus, to keep track of the plus/minus signs appearing in the coordinates of the vertices.